# k-d tree implementation in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, tree

I've written a k-d tree implementation in C++11 in order to learn and practice the finer points of the language. I'd appreciate feedback on the code, e.g. is it good C++ code, missing functionality, could it be optimized, etc?

I have written unit test (I can post separately), if anyone suspects bugs, I'm willing to post the test code separately.

```
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;

template <unsigned int K> class kd_tree_iterator;

template <unsigned int K>
class kd_tree
{
public:

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    class kd_point
    {
    private:
        array<float, K> Coords;

    public:
        kd_point() { Coords.fill(0.0f); }

        kd_point(initializer_list<float> l)
        {
            unsigned i = 0;

            for (initializer_list<float>::iterator It = l.begin(); It < l.end(); It++, i++)
                Coords[i] = *It;
        }

        void fill(float val) { Coords.fill(val); }

              float& operator[](std::size_t idx)       { return Coords[idx]; }
        const float& operator[](std::size_t idx) const { return const_cast<float&>(Coords[idx]); }

        bool operator==(const kd_point& rhs) const { return Coords == rhs.Coords; }
        bool operator!=(const kd_point& rhs) const { return Coords != rhs.Coords; }
        bool operator<(const kd_point& rhs) const { return Coords < rhs.Coords; }
        bool operator>(const kd_point& rhs) const { return Coords > rhs.Coords; }
        bool operator<=(const kd_point& rhs) const { return Coords <= rhs.Coords; }
        bool operator>=(const kd_point& rhs) const { return Coords >= rhs.Coords; }

        bool isValid() const
        {
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < K; i++)
                if ( isnan(Coords[i]) ||
                     Coords[i] ==  numeric_limits<float>::infinity() ||
                     Coords[i] == -numeric_limits<float>::infinity() )
                  return false;

            return true;
        }
    };  // kd_point

    class kd_point_Hasher
    {
    public:
        std::size_t operator()(const kd_point& k) const
        {
            size_t retVal = 0;

            for (unsigned index = 0; index < K; index++)
                retVal ^= hash<float>()(k[index]);

            return retVal;
        }
    };

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    using kd_Box = pair<kd_point, kd_point>;

protected:

    // Node class - internal to KD tree

    class kd_node
    {
    public:
        virtual bool isInternal() const = 0;
        virtual void SearchKdTree(const kd_Box &searchBox, vector<kd_point> &Points, const unsigned Depth = 0) const = 0;

        virtual void FindNearestNeighbor(const kd_point &srcPoint, kd_point &nearPoint,
                                         float &minDistance, kd_Box &minRegion, const unsigned int Depth = 0) const = 0;

        virtual void FindKNearestNeighbors(const kd_point &srcPoint, vector<kd_point> &nearPoints, const unsigned k,
                                           float &minDistance, kd_Box &minRegion, unordered_set<kd_point, kd_point_Hasher> &nearSet,
                                           const unsigned int Depth = 0) const = 0;

        virtual unsigned TreeHeight() const = 0;
        virtual unsigned nodeCount(bool withInternalNodes) const = 0;
        virtual kd_Box boundingBox() const = 0;
    };

    // Internal node class

    class kd_internal_node : public kd_node
    {
    private:
        float m_splitVal;
        kd_Box m_boundingBox;
        shared_ptr<kd_node> m_Left, m_Right;

    public:
        kd_internal_node(const float splitVal, kd_Box &boundingBox, shared_ptr<kd_node> Left) :
            m_splitVal(splitVal), m_boundingBox(boundingBox), m_Left(Left) {}

        kd_internal_node(const float splitVal, kd_Box &boundingBox, shared_ptr<kd_node> Left, shared_ptr<kd_node> Right) :
            m_splitVal(splitVal), m_boundingBox(boundingBox), m_Left(Left), m_Right(Right) {}

        float splitVal() const { return m_splitVal; }

        shared_ptr<kd_node> Left() const { return m_Left; }
        shared_ptr<kd_node> Right() const { return m_Right; }

        virtual bool isInternal() const override { return true; }

        virtual kd_Box boundingBox() const override { return m_boundingBox; }

        virtual void SearchKdTree(const kd_Box &searchBox, vector<kd_point> &Points, const unsigned Depth) const override
        {
            if (regionCrossesRegion(searchBox, m_Left->boundingBox()))
                m_Left->SearchKdTree(searchBox, Points, Depth + 1);

            if (m_Right != nullptr && regionCrossesRegion(searchBox, m_Right->boundingBox()))
                m_Right->SearchKdTree(searchBox, Points, Depth + 1);
        }

        virtual void FindKNearestNeighbors(const kd_point &srcPoint, vector<kd_point> &nearPoints, const unsigned k,
                                           float &minDistance, kd_Box &minRegion, unordered_set<kd_point, kd_point_Hasher> &nearSet,
                                           const unsigned int Depth = 0) const override
        {
            if (regionCrossesRegion(m_Left->boundingBox(), minRegion))
                m_Left->FindKNearestNeighbors(srcPoint, nearPoints, k, minDistance, minRegion, nearSet, Depth + 1);

            if (m_Right != nullptr && regionCrossesRegion(m_Right->boundingBox(), minRegion))
                m_Right->FindKNearestNeighbors(srcPoint, nearPoints, k, minDistance, minRegion, nearSet, Depth + 1);
        }

        virtual void FindNearestNeighbor(const kd_point &srcPoint, kd_point &nearPoint,
                                         float &minDistance, kd_Box &minRegion, const unsigned int Depth = 0) const override
        {
            if (regionCrossesRegion(m_Left->boundingBox(), minRegion))
                m_Left->FindNearestNeighbor(srcPoint, nearPoint, minDistance, minRegion, Depth + 1);

            if (m_Right != nullptr && regionCrossesRegion(m_Right->boundingBox(), minRegion))
                m_Right->FindNearestNeighbor(srcPoint, nearPoint, minDistance, minRegion, Depth + 1);
        }

        virtual unsigned TreeHeight() const override
        {
            return 1 + max(m_Left->TreeHeight(),
                           m_Right != nullptr ? m_Right->TreeHeight() : 0);
        }

        virtual unsigned nodeCount(bool withInternalNodes) const override
        {
            return withInternalNodes ? 1 : 0 +
                   m_Left->nodeCount(withInternalNodes) +
                   ( m_Right != nullptr ? m_Right->nodeCount(withInternalNodes) : 0 ) ;
        }
    };


    // Lead node

    class kd_leaf_node : public kd_node
    {
    private:
        kd_point m_pointCoords;

    public:
        weak_ptr<kd_leaf_node> m_Next, m_Prev;

        kd_leaf_node(const kd_point &Point) : m_pointCoords(Point) { }

        kd_point pointCoords() const { return m_pointCoords; }

        virtual bool isInternal() const override { return false; }

        virtual unsigned TreeHeight() const override { return 1; }

        virtual unsigned nodeCount(bool withInternalNodes) const override { return 1; }

        virtual void SearchKdTree(const kd_Box &searchBox, vector<kd_point> &Points, const unsigned Depth) const override
        {
            if (pointIsInRegion(m_pointCoords, searchBox))
                Points.push_back(m_pointCoords);
        }

        virtual kd_Box boundingBox() const override
        {
            kd_Box bounding_box;

            bounding_box.first = bounding_box.second = m_pointCoords;

            return bounding_box;
        }

        virtual void FindNearestNeighbor(const kd_point &srcPoint, kd_point &nearPoint,
                                         float &minDistance, kd_Box &minRegion, const unsigned int Depth = 0) const override
        {
            if (Distance(srcPoint, m_pointCoords) <= minDistance)
            {
                nearPoint = m_pointCoords;
                minDistance = Distance(srcPoint, nearPoint);

                for (unsigned index = 0; index < K; index++)
                {
                    minRegion.first[index] = srcPoint[index] - minDistance;
                    minRegion.second[index] = srcPoint[index] + minDistance;
                }
            }
        }

        virtual void FindKNearestNeighbors(const kd_point &srcPoint, vector<kd_point> &nearPoints, const unsigned k,
                                           float &minDistance, kd_Box &minRegion, unordered_set<kd_point, kd_point_Hasher> &nearSet,
                                           const unsigned int Depth = 0) const override
        {
            if (Distance(srcPoint, m_pointCoords) <= minDistance && nearSet.find(m_pointCoords) == nearSet.end())
            {
                nearSet.erase(nearPoints[k - 1]);
                nearSet.insert(m_pointCoords);

                nearPoints[k - 1] = m_pointCoords;

                for (unsigned i = k - 1; i > 0; i--)
                    if (Distance(srcPoint, nearPoints[i - 1]) > Distance(srcPoint, nearPoints[i]))
                        swap(nearPoints[i - 1], nearPoints[i]);
                    else
                        break;

                minDistance = Distance(srcPoint, nearPoints[k - 1]);

                for (unsigned index = 0; index < K; index++)
                {
                    minRegion.first[index] = srcPoint[index] - minDistance;
                    minRegion.second[index] = srcPoint[index] + minDistance;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // --------------------------------

    shared_ptr<kd_node> m_Root;
    weak_ptr<kd_leaf_node> m_firstLeaf;

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // The routine has a desired side effect of sorting Points
    float NthCoordMedian(vector<kd_point> &Points, const unsigned num)
    {
        sort(Points.begin(), Points.end(), [num](kd_point &A, kd_point &B) { return A[num%K] < B[num%K]; });

        float Median = Points[Points.size() / 2][num];

        if (Points.size() % 2 == 0)
            Median = (Median + Points[Points.size() / 2 - 1][num]) / 2.0f;

        if (Median == Points[Points.size() - 1][num] &&
            Median != Points[0][num])
        {
            int index = Points.size() / 2;

            while (Median == Points[--index][num]);

            Median = (Median + Points[index][num]) / 2.0f;
        }

        return Median;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    shared_ptr<kd_node> CreateTree(vector<kd_point> &Points, shared_ptr<kd_leaf_node> &Last_Leaf, const unsigned int Depth = 0)
    {
        if (Points.size() == 1)
        {
            shared_ptr<kd_leaf_node> retNode(new kd_leaf_node(Points[0]));

            if (Last_Leaf)
            {
                Last_Leaf->m_Next = retNode;
                retNode->m_Prev = Last_Leaf;
            }
            else
                m_firstLeaf = retNode;

            Last_Leaf = retNode;

            return retNode;
        }
        else if (Points.size() == 2)
        {
            if (Points[0][Depth%K] == Points[1][Depth%K])
            {
                shared_ptr<kd_node> Left = CreateTree(Points, Last_Leaf, Depth + 1);

                shared_ptr<kd_internal_node> retNode(new kd_internal_node(Points[0][Depth%K], Left->boundingBox(), Left));

                return retNode;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Points[0][Depth%K] > Points[1][Depth%K])
                    swap(Points[0], Points[1]);

                shared_ptr<kd_leaf_node> Left(new kd_leaf_node(Points[0])), Right(new kd_leaf_node(Points[1]));

                if (Last_Leaf)
                {
                    Last_Leaf->m_Next = Left;
                    Left->m_Prev = Last_Leaf;
                }
                else
                    m_firstLeaf = Left;

                Left->m_Next = Right;
                Right->m_Prev = Left;

                Last_Leaf = Right;

                kd_Box boundingBox;

                for (unsigned i = 0; i < K; i++)
                {
                    boundingBox.first[i]  = min(Points[0][i], Points[1][i]);
                    boundingBox.second[i] = max(Points[0][i], Points[1][i]);
                }

                shared_ptr<kd_internal_node> retNode(new
                    kd_internal_node((Points[0][Depth%K] + Points[1][Depth%K]) / 2.0f, boundingBox, Left, Right));

                return retNode;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            float Median = NthCoordMedian(Points, Depth%K);

            vector<kd_point> subtreePoints;
            shared_ptr<kd_node> Left, Right;

            subtreePoints.reserve(Points.size()/2);

            for (size_t index = 0; index < Points.size() && Points[index][Depth%K] <= Median; index++)
                subtreePoints.push_back(Points[index]);

            if (subtreePoints.size() > 0)
                Left = CreateTree(subtreePoints, Last_Leaf, Depth + 1);

            unsigned int insertedPoints = subtreePoints.size();
            unsigned int remainedPoints = Points.size() - subtreePoints.size();

            subtreePoints.resize(remainedPoints); subtreePoints.shrink_to_fit();

            for (size_t index = insertedPoints; index < Points.size(); index++)
                subtreePoints[index - insertedPoints] = Points[index];

            if (subtreePoints.size() > 0)
                Right = CreateTree(subtreePoints, Last_Leaf, Depth + 1);

            subtreePoints.resize(0); subtreePoints.shrink_to_fit();

            kd_Box boundingBox;

            if (Right)
            {
                kd_Box lbb = Left->boundingBox(),
                       rbb = Right->boundingBox();

                for (unsigned i = 0; i < K; i++)
                {
                    boundingBox.first[i] = min(lbb.first[i], rbb.first[i]);
                    boundingBox.second[i] = max(lbb.second[i], rbb.second[i]);
                }
            }
            else
                boundingBox = Left->boundingBox();

            shared_ptr<kd_internal_node> retNode(new kd_internal_node(Median, boundingBox, Left, Right));

            return retNode;
        }
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    shared_ptr<kd_leaf_node> ApproxNearestNeighborNode(const kd_point &srcPoint) const
    {
        unsigned int Depth = 0;
        shared_ptr<kd_node> Node(m_Root);

        while (Node->isInternal())
        {
            shared_ptr<kd_internal_node> iNode = static_pointer_cast<kd_internal_node>(Node);

            if (srcPoint[Depth++%K] <= iNode->splitVal() || iNode->Right() == nullptr)
                Node = iNode->Left();
            else
                Node = iNode->Right();
        }

        shared_ptr<kd_leaf_node> lNode = static_pointer_cast<kd_leaf_node>(Node);

        return lNode;
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------

    float ApproxNearestNeighborDistance(const kd_point &srcPoint) const
    {
        shared_ptr<kd_leaf_node> node = ApproxNearestNeighborNode(srcPoint);

        return Distance(srcPoint, node->pointCoords());
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------

    void PrintTree(shared_ptr<kd_node> node, unsigned int depth = 0) const
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < depth; i++)
            cout << " ";

        if (node == nullptr)
            cout << "null" << endl;
        else
        {
            if (node->isInternal())
            {
                shared_ptr<kd_internal_node> iNode = static_pointer_cast<kd_internal_node>(node);

                cout << "Split val is " << iNode->splitVal() << " for axis #" << depth%K + 1 << endl;

                PrintTree(iNode->m_Left, depth + 1);
                PrintTree(iNode->m_Right, depth + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                shared_ptr<kd_leaf_node> lNode = static_pointer_cast<kd_leaf_node>(node);

                cout << "Point is (";

                for (unsigned i = 0; i < K; i++)
                    cout << lNode->m_Vals[i] << " ";

                cout << ")" << endl;
            }
        }
    }

public:
    kd_tree() { }
    kd_tree(const kd_tree &obj) = delete;
    kd_tree(vector<kd_point> &Points) { insert(Points); }

    bool operator==(const kd_tree<K> rhs) = delete;
    bool operator=(const kd_tree<K> rhs) = delete;

    void clear() { m_Root.reset(); m_firstLeaf.reset(); }

    friend class kd_tree_iterator<K>;
    typedef typename kd_tree_iterator<K> iterator;

    kd_tree_iterator<K> end();
    kd_tree_iterator<K> begin();

    static bool pointIsInRegion(const kd_point &Point, const pair<kd_point, kd_point> &Region);
    static bool regionCrossesRegion(const pair<kd_point, kd_point> &Region1, const pair<kd_point, kd_point> &Region2);

    static float Distance(const kd_point &P, const kd_point &Q);

    // ----------------------------------

    void insert(vector<kd_point> &Points)
    {
        clear();

        for (signed i = Points.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            if (!Points[i].isValid())
                Points.erase(Points.begin() + i);

        if (Points.size() > 0)
        {
            sort(Points.begin(), Points.end());
            vector<kd_point>::iterator it = unique(Points.begin(), Points.end());
            Points.resize(distance(Points.begin(), it));

            shared_ptr<kd_leaf_node> dummyLeaf;

            m_Root = CreateTree(Points, dummyLeaf);
        }
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    void search(const kd_point &minPoint, const kd_point &maxPoint, vector<kd_point> &Points) const
    {
        Points.clear();

        if (m_Root == nullptr)
            return;

        kd_Box sorted;

        for (unsigned coord = 0; coord < K; coord++)
        {
            sorted.first[coord] = min(minPoint[coord], maxPoint[coord]);
            sorted.second[coord] = max(minPoint[coord], maxPoint[coord]);
        }

        m_Root->SearchKdTree(sorted, Points);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    bool FindNearestNeighbor(const kd_point &srcPoint, kd_point &nearPoint) const
    {
        bool retVal = (m_Root != nullptr);

        if (!m_Root)
            nearPoint.fill(numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN());
        else
        {
            float minDistance = ApproxNearestNeighborDistance(srcPoint);

            kd_Box minBox;

            for (unsigned coord = 0; coord < K; coord++)
            {
                minBox.first[coord] = srcPoint[coord] - minDistance;
                minBox.second[coord] = srcPoint[coord] + minDistance;
            }

            m_Root->FindNearestNeighbor(srcPoint, nearPoint, minDistance, minBox);
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    bool FindKNearestNeighbors(const kd_point &srcPoint, vector<kd_point> &nearPoints, const unsigned k) const
    {
        nearPoints.clear();
        nearPoints.reserve(k);

        if (!m_Root) return false;

        shared_ptr<kd_leaf_node> nNode = ApproxNearestNeighborNode(srcPoint),
                                 pNode = nNode->m_Prev.lock();

        nearPoints.push_back(nNode->pointCoords());

        nNode = nNode->m_Next.lock();

        while (nearPoints.size() < k && ( nNode || pNode ))
        {
            if (nNode)
            {
                nearPoints.push_back(nNode->pointCoords());

                nNode = nNode->m_Next.lock();
            }

            if (pNode && nearPoints.size() < k)
            {
                nearPoints.push_back(pNode->pointCoords());

                pNode = pNode->m_Prev.lock();
            }
        }

        sort(nearPoints.begin(), nearPoints.end(),
             [srcPoint](kd_point &A, kd_point &B) {return Distance(srcPoint, A) < Distance(srcPoint, B); });

        float minDistance;

        if (nearPoints.size() < k)
        {
            kd_point infinityPoint;
            infinityPoint.fill(numeric_limits<float>::infinity());

            nearPoints.resize(k, infinityPoint);

            minDistance = numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
        }
        else
            minDistance = Distance(srcPoint,nearPoints[k - 1]);

        kd_Box MinBox;

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < K; i++)
        {
            MinBox.first[i]  = srcPoint[i] - minDistance;
            MinBox.second[i] = srcPoint[i] + minDistance;
        }

        unordered_set<kd_point, kd_point_Hasher> nearSet(nearPoints.begin(), nearPoints.end());

        m_Root->FindKNearestNeighbors(srcPoint, nearPoints, k, minDistance, MinBox, nearSet);

        for (signed i = k - 1; i > 0 && !nearPoints[i].isValid(); i--)
            nearPoints.erase(nearPoints.begin() + i);

        return true;
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------

    unsigned nodeCount(bool withInternalNodes = false) const
    {
        return m_Root != nullptr ? m_Root->nodeCount(withInternalNodes) : 0;
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------

    unsigned TreeHeight() const
    {
        return this->m_Root != nullptr ? m_Root->TreeHeight() : 0;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------

    void PrintTree() const { PrintTree(m_Root); }
};

// -------------------------------------------------------------

template <unsigned int K>
float kd_tree<K>::Distance(const kd_point &P, const kd_point &Q)
{
    float Sum = 0;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < K; i++)
        Sum += (P[i] - Q[i]) * (P[i] - Q[i]);

    return sqrtf(Sum);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <unsigned int K>
bool kd_tree<K>::pointIsInRegion(const kd_point &Point, const pair<kd_point, kd_point> &Region)
{
    bool isInRegion = true;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < K && isInRegion; i++)
        if (!(Region.first[i] <= Point[i] && Point[i] <= Region.second[i]))
            isInRegion = false;

    return isInRegion;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <unsigned int K>
bool kd_tree<K>::regionCrossesRegion(const pair<kd_point, kd_point> &Region1,
                                     const pair<kd_point, kd_point> &Region2)
{
    bool regionsCross = true;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < K && regionsCross; i++)
        if (Region1.first[i] > Region2.second[i] || Region1.second[i] < Region2.first[i])
            regionsCross = false;

    return regionsCross;
}

// -----------------------
//
// Iterator implementation
//
template <unsigned int K>
class kd_tree_iterator : public std::iterator<output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>
{
public:
    kd_tree_iterator() {}
    kd_tree_iterator(shared_ptr<typename kd_tree<K>::kd_leaf_node> node) : nodePtr(node) {}

    template <unsigned int K> friend bool operator== (const kd_tree_iterator<K>& lhs, const kd_tree_iterator<K>& rhs);
    template <unsigned int K> friend bool operator!= (const kd_tree_iterator<K>& lhs, const kd_tree_iterator<K>& rhs);

    typename kd_tree<K>::kd_point& operator*()
    {
        return this->nodePtr->pointCoords();
    }

    kd_tree_iterator& operator++()
    {
        this->nodePtr = this->nodePtr->m_Next.lock();

        return *this;
    }

    kd_tree_iterator operator++(int)
    {
        kd_tree_iterator tmp(*this);
        operator++();
        return tmp;
    }

private:
    shared_ptr<typename kd_tree<K>::kd_leaf_node> nodePtr;
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <unsigned int K>
bool operator== (const kd_tree_iterator<K>& lhs, const kd_tree_iterator<K>& rhs)
{
    return (lhs.nodePtr == rhs.nodePtr);
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <unsigned int K>
bool operator!= (const kd_tree_iterator<K> &lhs, const kd_tree_iterator<K>& rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}

// -----------------------------------

template <unsigned int K>
kd_tree_iterator<K> kd_tree<K>::end()
{
    kd_tree<K>::iterator retVal;

    return retVal;
}

// -------------------------------------

template <unsigned int K>
kd_tree_iterator<K> kd_tree<K>::begin()
{
    if (!this->m_Root)
        return end();
    else
        return m_firstLeaf.lock();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with kd-trees, so I can't give you any specific comments there. But I can give you lots of C++ comments. This is by no means an exhaustive review either, it's a lot of code!

---

First of all, see [why is using namespace std considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2069064) This is especially important in light of the fact that this is a header, so anybody who include your kd-tree implementation now has their namespace polluted. This is very bad.

**`kd_point`**

This class doesn't need to exist. You should simply use:

```
using kd_point = std::array<float, K>;
```

Otherwise, you're just reimplementing a bunch of functionality and your `initializer_list` constructor is less efficient than the normal aggregate initialization of `std::array`. You could simply have done:

```
kd_point(std::initializer_list<float> lst)
{
    std::copy(std::begin(lst), std::end(lst), std::begin(Coords));
}
```

Avoid using `l` as a variable name. It's hard to distinguish from `1`. Also capitalized names typically indicated classes, not variables, so that's a little confusing.

**`kd_tree_iterator`**

I'm not sure why you have every other class private to `kd_tree` but this one public. You can throw this in there as well. One major bug here is that your dereference operator is:

```
typename kd_tree<K>::kd_point& operator*()
{
    return this->nodePtr->pointCoords();
}
```

but `pointCoords()` in `kd_leaf_node` returns:

```
kd_point pointCoords() const { return m_pointCoords; }
```

So you're left with a dangling reference. So you likely want `kd_leaf_node` to return a reference to const `kd_point` instead.

You marked `kd_tree_iterator` as an `output_iterator`. But it's not an output iterator. It's a forward iterator! You'll have to fix all the `void`s to be the correct types there. When you write a default constructor that does nothing, prefer to write `= default`. Also, there's no reason to do an *extra* copy of your node while passing it in. Take the argument by reference to const:

```
kd_tree_iterator(shared_ptr<kd_leaf_node> const& node)
: node(node)
{ }
```

Also, rather than typing `operator++()` in the postfix increment operator, it's more canonical to write `++*this;`. Just writing out `operator` is weird.

**`kd_point_Hasher`**

This isn't a very good hash. The problem is something like `(1,2)` and `(2,1)` hash to the same value, so it's limited. You want to add a shift. You should take a look at [`boost::hash_combine`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine) for this. Additionally, since we're doing C++11 and now `kd_point` is just an `array`, you can use a range-based for-expression for clarity:

```
std::size_t operator()(const kd_point& p) const
{
    std::size_t retVal = 0;
    for (float f : p) {
        boost::hash_combine(retVal, f);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

**Return when you know the value**

Just looking at some of your functions like `pointIsInRegion` and `regionCrossesRegion`. Once you know the answer is `false`, you're done. So you can stop there - you don't have to keep going. For example:

```
bool pointIsInRegion(const kd_point& point, const std::pair<kd_point, kd_point>& region)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < K; ++i) {
        if (!(region.first[i] <= point[i] && point[i] <= region.second[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Though really that could be simplified into:

```
bool pointIsInRegion(const kd_point& point, const std::pair<kd_point, kd_point>& region)
{
    return region.first <= point && point <= region.second;
}
```

**`float`?**

Why `float` and not `double`?

**Hierarchy**

You have this hierarchy for `kd_node` to handle separately the cases of internal nodes and leaf nodes. Why? A leaf is just a node without children, it doesn't need to be a separate type. Is there some advantage to the hierarchy? It seems to overcomplicate the problem. `kd_node` should just be all the nodes. You can implement, e.g. `isInternal()`, based on whether or not the node has children without having to make it `virtual`.

**Check your signatures**

Some of the signatures of these functions could be improved. For example, you have:

```
void search(const kd_point &minPoint, const kd_point &maxPoint, vector<kd_point> &Points) const
```

Why is a function named `search` `void`? It should actually search for things:

```
std::vector<kd_point> search(const kd_point &minPoint, const kd_point &maxPoint) const
```

The same could be said for a lot of other functions. `FindNearestNeighbor{,s}` are also `void` for instance.

Comment: Thank you - this helps me learn C++11 a lot, which is a big part of what I was hoping to get from the code review.

Comment: A comment about hierarchy - an internal node has a single value indicating where the hyper plane splits space, while the leaf has k values to give the full k-d point position in space, so the two node types have no data members in common.